Warning "Danger: Do not type or paste anything here..."
I'm currently making a login page for a service and after sending a fetch request to the server to check the username and password, once the reponse on the client side arrives there is that warning in the console:

I'm pretty sure that this warning comes from the psono extension, because when disabling all extensions or using a different browser it does not show this warning and it always is logged in the console when the notification bar of the extension that asks if the password should be saved is shown.
Furthermore there is this request under the network tab that has failed, I'm not really sure how it relates to this, but maybe someone here can get some information from it:

What exactly does this warning mean and why is it displayed? Also I'm not that knowledgeable in security measures for nodejs applications, so any further tipps and recommendation are welcome.
EDIT
I also just remembered that I've added "use strict" to basically all *.js files I have, could that be the reason why it shows this warning?

What is the question?

@Konrad I've edited the question. Basically I want to understand what this warning is and why its being displayed. Sorry for not making the question clear.

It's just a console.log with styles. You can try pressing the blue bundle.min.js text to see which files prints it. It is usually used to warn non-tech users about pasting unknown code into the browser's console.

Well the thing is, during the time the extension notification bar is present, the file indicated is index.js and when it disappears it changes to bundle.min.js. But that file does not really exist, the name is not clickable.

"I also just remembered that I've added "use strict" to basically all *.js files I have, could that be the reason why it shows this warning?" - no

After checking in the next day it was gone. Don't know why, but I guess that works for me
